# .classpath / .settings folder exists in Eclipse but I can't find it

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to add some files to .settings folder / .classpath. Eclipse says these files exist, but I can't find them. Where should I look?

Comment: How are you looking for them? Project explorer? Package explorer?

Comment: Project explorer and in the workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project Explorer doesn't normally show files and folders starting with '.'

To change this click the view menu on the explorer tool bar (the small triangle). Select 'Filters and Customization...'. In the resulting menu deselect '.* resources' from the filters list.

Note: editing these files directly can cause problems.